# Alert-block in Jupyter notebook VScode

Tags: html, visual-studio, jupyter-notebook, styling

I would like to create an alert-block in a Jupyter-notebook using this code:

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-danger"> In general, just avoid the red boxes. </div>
```

When I try this in a Jupyter-notebook via Anaconda-navigator it works like this:

[image]

When I try the exact same code in VS code it returns the following:

[image]

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this in vscode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple months later and it now works using a newer version `1.0.17` of VScode. Here is now the output using the follwing code in Jupyter notebook:

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-danger"> In general, just avoid the red boxes. </div>
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see the alert-blocks are now currently visible. It is also mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/10422).